# IE Z-Index/Hover issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with z-index. On chrome and FF it works great, except on IE 8 ofcourse.

what i try:

```
<container>
  <inputfield>
  <overlay-of-the-inputfield>
</container>
```

The 'overlay' should be on top of the inputfield and making the inputfield unselectable.
The overloy works on FF but not on IE.

The source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.input-overlay{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:15px;
    height:16px;
    border:2px solid #A0C8FA;
    border-radius:2px;
}        
.input-overlay:focus{
    border:2px groove #A0C8FA;
    border-radius:2px;
}    
.input-overlay:hover{
    border:2px dashed #4D82C4;
    border-radius:2px;
z-index:150;
}
.input-checkbox-textfield{
    width:15px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}    
.inputfield-checkbox{
    width:15px;
    border:none;
    padding-left:4px;
    font-weight:700;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX:10;">
    <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 100" 
         id="indonesier_uiterlijkIDOverlay" 
         class="input-overlay"
         tabIndex="5">
     </DIV>
    <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1" 
         class="input-checkbox-textfield">
             <INPUT type="text"
                    style="Z-INDEX: 1;" 
                    id="inputField" 
                    value="X"
                    class="inputfield-checkbox"/> 
    </DIV>
</DIV>    
</body>
</html>
```

The hover doesnt get triggered on IE when moving the mouse in the center of the inputfield. Also the 'X' stays selectable.

if i add:

.input-overlay
**background-color:blue;**

Then it works in IE, but making the inputfield disappear.

Does any one know the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a problem with z-index. Positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Try setting z-index to the parent element with more than a 1000. For more info find out on http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/